# Converting second element in a tuple to an integer

Tags: python, list, tuples, element

I am trying to get rid of the '  ' in the 2nd element of each tuple.

my code is

```
def read_records_from_file(filename):
    final_list = []
    infile=open(filename)
    lines=infile.readlines()
    i = 0
    while i < len(lines):
        element = lines[i]
        i += 1
        if element.strip() == '<begin step data>':
            break

    while i < len(lines):       
        element = lines[i]
        clean_element = element.rstrip("\n")
        list = clean_element.split(",")
        tuple1 = tuple(list)
        i += 1
        if element.strip() == '<end step data>':
            break         
        final_list.append(tuple1)
    return final_list
```

my code gives me

```
[('2001-01-01', '12776'), ('2001-01-02', '15128')]
```

but I need

```
[('2001-01-01', 12776), ('2001-01-02', 15128)]
```

I am not sure how to only change the 2nd element of each tuple to integer.

Note: I am not allowed to use for loops

Any help is much-appreciated Thanks!

Comment: What is your input?

Comment: I get a file of random lines, i have to open the file and begin reading when the line <begin step data> appears and then stop when <end step data appears>. The lines in between those two are of the nature 2004-03-25,4297

Comment: why are you not allowed to use `for` loops?

Comment: To practice for while loops I guess. Very frustrating

Comment: :/ but what you're doing is practicing using while loops when you should be using for loops - which is to say _misusing_ while loops. but anyway, nevermind, I hope you're learning and enjoying.

Comment: for looping would be very handy for this issue :) I would just leave it but i need this function for a larger module :/

Answer (score 2):

You have to cast the second `tuple` entry to the `int` data type and not use a `string` representation (this gives you the quotation marks):

```
 list = clean_element.split(",")
 tuple1 = (list[0], int(list[1]))
```

Edit: Please move these lines to the beginning of your second while loop:

```
element = lines[i]
if element.strip() == '<end step data>':
    break
```

to solve your second problem.

In the end, you get this code:

```
def read_records_from_file(filename):
    final_list = []
    infile=open(filename)
    lines=infile.readlines()

    for i in range(len(lines)):  
        element = lines[i]
        clean_element = element.rstrip("\n").strip()
        if clean_element == '<end step data>':
            break     

        list = clean_element.split(",")
        tuple1 = tuple(list)

        final_list.append(tuple1)
    return final_list
```

Comment: I have put this into my code and it give me a syntax error for the line if element.strip() == '<end step data>': do you know why this is?

Comment: @MartinLopez If this response has solved your issue, please vote it up and mark it as the answer to your question.

Comment: @FlashTek I would avoid using `list` as a variable name

Comment: I now have the same error for final_list.append(tuple1)

Comment: (i didn't realise that was from the question, but I stand by it)

Comment: @FlashTek I am not allowed to use for loops.

Comment: @FlashTek Give up. Unreasonable OP's like this aren't worth the effort.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, sorry if i am being difficult, this is what the question i am doing is asking of me. I tried for a very long time to get to my answer and i thought string to integer would be easier than this. Thanks for trying

Comment: @MartinLopez Try to stand on your own two feet. FlashTek has already helped you a lot. Why can't you figure out the rest yourself? If you don't learn now, you never will.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ That part of my code was working before, he told me to put in his code and it caused other problems.